# Insert through ajax then fade in content with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, forms

So I currently have my form that submits the data to my database..But now I'm wondering how I go about printing this data into the page.

I've been told I must use javascript to do this, but the problem is I have a like and dislike button a comments button a delete button and my profile image within a div that has a postid to delete which is under the form within my profile.php. I need all this implemented also. Is this a huge task? And what do I need to do it.

As an example. When you ask a question on here, it sends the data through ajax then prints the post out with its edit, delete etc buttons without reloading the page. I'm looking to do something similar.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#myform").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var toid = $("#toid").val();
        var newmsg = $("#newmsg").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: "toid=" + content + "&newmsg=" + newmsg,
            success: function(){alert('success');}
        });
    });
});


<form id="myform"  method="POST"  class="form_statusinput">
<input type="hidden"  name="toid" id="toid" value="<?php echo $user1_id; ?>">
<input class="input" name="newmsg" id="newmsg" placeholder="Say something" autocomplete="off">
<div id="button_block">
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Feed">
</div>
</form>
```

COMMENT LINK

```
echo "<div class='stream_option'><a style='cursor:pointer;' id='commenttoggle_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' onclick=\"toggle_comments('comment_holder_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."');clearTimeout(streamloop);swapcommentlabel(this.id);\"> Write a comment...</a></div>";
}else{
echo "<div class='stream_option'><a style='cursor:pointer;' id='commenttoggle_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' onclick=\"toggle_comments('comment_holder_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."');clearTimeout(streamloop);swapcommentlabel(this.id);\"> Show Comments (".$num2.")</a></div>";
```

LIKE LINK

```
cho "<div class='stream_option'><a id='likecontext_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"likestatus(".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'].",this.id);\">";
```

DISLIKE LINK

```
echo "<div class='stream_option'><a id='dislikecontext_".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' style='cursor:pointer;' onClick=\"dislikestatus(".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'].",this.id);\">";
```

DELETE LINK

```
<? if($streamitem_data['streamitem_creator']==$_SESSION['id']){
echo "<div style='cursor:pointer;position:relative;top:-70px;float:right;padding-right:5px;' onclick=\"delete_('".$streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."');\">X</div>";}
```

Comment: Printing what data? The data typed in the form, or are your returning something from the server, cause it does'nt look like you are ?

Comment: Yeah the data typed in the form. 

But how do I go about putting the like, dislike, comment and delete button into the same div too as they're not sent through the above ajax.
Without the ajax, all the functionality is in my home.php page the like, dislike, comments and delete button. I just don't know how to add all this as I'm not up on Ajax/Javascript and with no examples around it confuses me greatly. And my home.php page is too big for people to be looking through.

Comment: I think you should provide more specific code, website, screenshots or anything that would make it more visual. Its extremely hard to second-guess all of your described buttons and etc.

Comment: Please show the `HTML Structure` of the element you're working with. We can get you started on the click functionality and sending/printing data from there. It sounds like you just need to send over the id of the user, and the action to take, such as `delete, like, comment, edit`.

Comment: Edited main question with the HTML Links.

Comment: So you want to accept data from your client's browser using something other than the `home.php` page? Of course, that's reasonable and entirely possible. Look into `REST`ful and `XML-RPC` techniques, or Model View Controller setups in general.

Comment: Is it possible to load the whole div in from the home.php on success with .load()